# TypeError in cython

Tags: python, cython

I have a cython program that is parsing billions of records.  However, in my output i am getting.

```
 TypeError: 'an integer is required' in cython_test.parse_func ignored
```

Is there any setting for compilation in which it will raise so I can find the line instead of cython handling the error and giving a warning?

Comment: Curious about the answer to this too. Usually, I simply put a lot of `print` statements in order to debug the issue, because Cython is impervious to `pdb`. Now, I have simply stopped using Cython because I didn't dig into how to get nicer errors, and just started using Numba after I read this post: https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2015/02/24/optimizing-python-with-numpy-and-numba/

Comment: I cannot use numba for this.  too many string operations.  its a poorly formed csv.

Comment: Well, then I suppose its time for this: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/debugging.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a number of native types, cython provides exception handling built in.

to propagate the exception, you need to define an exception.

for example:

```
  cdef int spam() except -1
```